# How to send variable in curl command to generate token?

Tags: authentication, curl, post, oauth, bearer-token

This is the curl command I'm using which generates a Bearer Token. The command has the following variables: $url(base url), $cid(clientid) and $csec(client secret). I have used the echo command and checked if the variables have stored correct value. If I replace the variables with their stored value then I'm able to fetch the Bearer Token.

`curl --request POST $url/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$cid&client_secret=$csec'`

I'm getting the following error when I run this command:

`{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Bad credentials"}`

I have tried using quotes and braces but still not getting any success.
These are the commands I have tried. Please let me know of any alternate approach.

`curl --request POST "$url"/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="$cid"&client_secret="$csec"' curl --request POST '"$url"'/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='"$cid"'&client_secret='"$csec"'' curl --request POST {$url}/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={$cid}&client_secret={$csec}'`

Comment: Are you sure that variables are expanded in a string enclosed in single quotes (`'`)?

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to enclose a string when you want variables to be expanded (see e.g. [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/)):

```bash
curl --request POST "$url/oauth/token" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$cid&client_secret=$csec"
```